# how to handle back stack in fragment with config changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation, fragment-backstack

```
Activity
   |
   |
Fragment1 --> Fragment2 --> Fragment3 --> Fragment4
                                        |
                                        |
                                    Orientation changed
                                        |
                                        |
                       Fragment3 <-- Fragment4
                            |
                            |
                       Fragment3 --> Fragment5 


 Scenario : 1. I am having an application with single activity with fragment.
            2. In oncreate of fragment i enabled setRetainInstance(true);
            3. After launching the activity i am navigating from fragment 1 to fragment 2 by added to back stack and commit.
            4. Same for fragment 2 to fragment 3 and fragment 3 to fragment 4.
            5. From fragment 4 i changed the orientation. As mentioned due to setRetainInstance(true);. Fragment 4 onViewCreated has called.
            6. But when go back to fragment 3 by pressing back button. And make a transcation from fragment 3 to frament 5. I got an exception "*
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

".

```
**As far as i searched i found few solution,
1. override onSavedInstance, dont call super method. [I dont want to use this]
2. And manifest declare , android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" [I dont want to use this] I want to handle config changes.**
```

Pls some one explain me what is the proper way of handling backstack fragments after orientation change. [Note : when i try to commit from fragment 3 to new fragment 5 it crashed.]

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
        transaction.replace(containerID, baseFragment,TAG);
        transaction.commit();
```